# Java-8 Get count with value in specific range

Tags: java, collections, java-8, java-stream

I have List of Products and want to find count of products in specific cost range like,
if productList is having 10 products with cost between 1-10, 50 between 11-100 and 100 between 101-1000, then it should return a map as follow,

> "1-10": 10 
>   "11-100": 50
>   "101:1000": 100

```
  class Product {
        long id;
        long cost;
        String name;
        //getters setters
    }
```

I tried many things but did not work,
    List productList = getProducts();

```
productList.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(//logic to get map));
```

Highly appreciate any help.

Answer (score 3):

You can create a `Function` for range and use `Collectors.groupingBy` as below,

```
Map<String, Long> countByCost = productList.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(costRange, TreeMap::new, Collectors.counting()));

Function<Product, String> costRange = ele -> {
        if(ele.cost >= 1 && ele.cost < 11)
            return "1-10";
        if(ele.cost >= 11 && ele.cost < 101)
            return "11-100";
        if(ele.cost >= 101 && ele.cost < 1001)
            return "101-1000";
        return "others";
 };
```

**UPDATE:**
More elegant Function for cost range as suggested by Holger,

```
Function<Product, String> costRange = ele -> {
 if(ele.cost < 1) return "others"; 
long i = ele.cost == 1? 1: (long)Math.pow(10, Math.floor(Math.log10(ele.cost-1))); 
return (i|1)+"-"+(i*10); };
```

Comment: don't `return null`, instead group them as `"others"`.

Comment: Worked perfectly.

Comment: It’s a bit pointless to use a `TreeMap` here, as it will order the keys lexicographically, not numerically. Further, `costRange` has to be defined before it is used. Instead of the `if` ladder, you can use a generalized function like `Function<Product, String> costRange = ele -> { if(ele.cost < 1) return "others";  long i = ele.cost == 1? 1: (long)Math.pow(10, Math.floor(Math.log10(ele.cost-1))); 
 return (i|1)+"-"+(i*10);  };`

Comment: @Holger Thanks for your valuable feedback. Even lexicographical order will result in valid order in this case. I could not even think of costRange function like this. It was a great learning for me.

Comment: Lexicographical order is `"1-10", "101-1000", "11-100"`, numerical order would be `"1-10", "11-100", "101-1000"`.